# Cannot POST using Angular JS

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

Hi I am trying to post data with AnguarJs but having some issues.My js code is below :

```
    var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
    app.constant('appUrl', 'http://localhost/zara/rest/');
 /*---- categories fetch code  -------*/  
    app.controller('myController',['$scope','$http','appUrl',  function($scope, $http , appUrl) {

      $scope.newName = "";
    $scope.postForm = function() {  
        var data = $.param({
                name: $scope.newName
            });

        $http.post("http://localhost/zara/rest/api_customerlogin.php", data).success(function(data, status) {
            $scope.hello = data;
            console.log(data);
        });
     };
  }]);
```

I am getting this error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'param' of undefined` And when i change code to like this one then i got this error.

```
<script>
    angular.module('myApp', [])
    .controller('myController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
        this.loginForm = function() {

            var user_data='user_email=' +this.inputData.email+'&user_password='+this.inputData.password;

            $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: 'login.php',
                data: user_data,
                headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
            })
            .success(function(data) {
        console.log(data);

            })
        }

    }]);
    </script>
```

Cannot post to login.html page.This is my first project on AnguarJs so not very familer with this.Thanks.

Comment: Did you try it in service file : app.serivce('service',[$http,function(){ }])

Comment: No I just tried the code with above codes.How will service work with this?

Comment: What's exactly `$.param` do for you?!, change your data to `object` as `var data = {name: $scope.newName}`

Comment: This error because `$` related to `jquery` and `jquery.param` is undefined

Comment: And another thing is much better if you use `$http` as service in angular.

Comment: you dont need use jquery to post data . You can do it with only angular . change to `var data = {name: $scope.newName}` and dont forget decoded json in php code

Comment: And if you want use $.param . include jquery in your app

Comment: I already added jquery on top of the page.But still got same issue.

Comment: @MahmoodRehman can you provide code in html page ? Input of `$scope.newName`

Answer (score 0):

In your first code you try to post to

```
http://localhost/zara/rest/api_customerlogin.php
```

Did you forget to change `login.php` in your second example to this url?

Comment: on the second I just paste code with a dummy URL.URL changing no effect on the code.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that post request may not working on local environment until you add allow-orgin-access plugin for your browser. But it works on actual working websites.

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.constant('appUrl', 'http://localhost/zara/rest/');

app.controller('myController',function($scope, service, appUrl){

   $scope.newName = "";
   $scope.loading = false;

   $scope.postForm = function() {

     var data = $.param({
            name: $scope.newName
         });

     $scope.loading = true;
     service.makeThisRequest(appUrl + 'api_customerlogin.php', data).then(function(data){
         $scope.hello = data;
         console.log(data);
      },function(error){
        console.log(error);
      }).finally(function(){
        $scope.loading = false;
      });

   });

}]);

app.factory('service', function ($http) {
    return {
      makeThisRequest : function(url,params){
        return $http.post(url,params);
      }
    };
});
```

Comment: explain `$.param` please ?! what's for?

Comment: Create a serialized representation of an array, a plain object, or a jQuery object suitable for use in a URL query string or Ajax request. In case a jQuery object is passed, it should contain input elements with name/value properties.

http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param/

Comment: I already added allow origin code on PHP side.

Comment: So what you got ?